# putting a class view in a template django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

django newb. I am just trying to include my class view in a template. The class view that I have is a CreateView, so i want to generate a form which i can submit. I see all sorts of info on the web for generating lists of objects etc, but nothing for a form. I am thinking this should not be that hard. I have the following:

models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=600, default="None")
```

views.py

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Comments
    fields = ['comment_text']
    template_name = 'commentcreate.html'
    context_object_name = 'comment_create'
```

my template

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ comment_create }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The template is mock, i really want to add this form to a completely different template which is part of another app. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: use `{{ form }}` instead of `{{ comment_create }}` or `{{ form.comment_text }}`

Comment: ok, but how does it know which form it is pointing to. If i have several CreateView classes, if i just say {form}, i don't see where if points to this specific view CommentCreate. I tried including this in another template, and the form does not display, i am assuming because there is no link to tell it which view to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `{{ form }}` to access all the fields defined inside your `view` class.

To access a specific field from the form, use dot operator, ie, `{{ form.db_field_name }}`

For ex,

```
{{ form.comment_text }}
```

This would create a `label`, `input` tags for the field `comment_text`.

You may also [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) the form as table or paragraph etc.

Comment: ok, but how does it know which form it is point to. If i have several CreateView classes, if i just say {form}, i don't see where if points to this specific view CommentCreate

Comment: it's connected though urls. ie, for ex `url(^post/create, views.CreateView.as_View(), name="create")` would invoke the corresponding view, which further invokes the template given. ACcesing the db fields in templates are through `{{ form }}` since your view class  inherited the CreateView class.

Comment: ok i understand that, and i was able to do this with only one template. But what if i already have a template and a url that is `url(^post/create, views.CreateView.as_View(), name="create")`, and i want to add another CreateView to this same template? How do i have both of them?

Comment: What i meant by createView in url is createViewclass corresponding to that url, in this case `Views.CommentCreate.as_view()`. I donno how you gave the same url for two createViews.

Comment: will createview only work for one model then? i have two models which i want so show in the same url

Comment: Then make your view class to inherit `TemplateView` and pass two model values to context . This code should be get method of view class, which shadows the default get method which got invoked when the request is of type GET

Comment: Think I answered your original question.